flutterfire flutterfire : The term 'flutterfire' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet
enter image description here
** flutterfire configure
flutterfire : The term 'flutterfire' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

flutterfire configure

  + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (flutterfire:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException**







dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
Package flutterfire_cli is currently active at version 0.2.7.
The package flutterfire_cli is already activated at newest available version.
To recompile executables, first run dart pub global deactivate flutterfire_cli.
Installed executable flutterfire.
Warning: Pub installs executables into C:\Users\YASH\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin, which is not on your path.
You can fix that by adding that directory to your system's "Path" environment variable.
A web search for "configure windows path" will show you how.
Activated flutterfire_cli 0.2.7.
after that i found this solution i use to wrong add to Edit environment variable set path
still geting error
now I should try to Edit SYSTEM environment variables for your account
Control panel => edit then paste path here
and here i got success.

It looks like you forgot to add the path to the flutterfire executable to your path. The instructions on how to do so are in the error message:

Pub installs executables into C:\Users\YASH\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin, which is not on your path.
You can fix that by adding that directory to your system's "Path" environment variable. A web search for "configure windows path" will show you how.
Activated flutterfire_cli 0.2.7.


i already set path to the env variable path , thats why after some  searching then i got solution its a env System Path  to set not env variable.
